# Is there a tool to convert Javadoc into C# XML documentation?

Tags: c#, javadoc, xml-documentation

Does anyone know of a tool that converts Javadoc comments into C# documentation comments?

Comment: Wow - major coincidence. I could swear I've just been musing about this for Noda Time ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) to generate your docs. This doesn't convert, but it should be able to create docs from javadoc-in-C#.